# How to use css to display aligned images, under IE and other browsers?

Tags: css

I would like to do the following by using CSS (instead of tables) :

- displaying images (with caption underneath)
- the images have different width (but the same height)
- the images should be vertically aligned
- by using css (as opposed to tables) the number of images per line would be automatically fit to the screen resolution

I tried the following css :

```
div.float {
    float: left;
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth < 443 ? "442px" : "auto" ); /* set min-width for IE */
    min-width: 442px; /* sets min-width value for all standards-compliant browsers */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Unfortunately such css works well under Firefox or Chrome, but does not work under Internet explorer 9.

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance, Patrick.

Comment: Could you make a quick image showing what you're after?

Comment: When you say the images should be vertically aligned: if they’re all the same height, surely they’ll be vertically aligned by default?

Answer (score 0):

http://phrogz.net/CSS/icons.html

(Note that this page is referring to 7-year-old web browser versions. Things are even better now.)